# sendmail segmentation fault

Tags: kernel, debian-lenny, segmentation-fault

We are using debian lenny on a server & we are using it for monitoring server & sending email for reporting. We are using sendmail to send emails.

We found the following error when we did not receive mail.

Error :-

debian kernel: [3029475.124022] sendEmail[15688]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000 sp bfffe15c error 4 in perl[8048000+131000]

Please help me too find the issue. Is this could be the problem with hardware???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this has been working in the past, no recent changes etc, I'd guess that you have a memory error. Try rebooting and running a memtest   See here for [memtest tutorial](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic62524.html)

If you can't reboot, I was just reading this interesting [ksplice blog](http://blog.ksplice.com/2010/06/attack-of-the-cosmic-rays/) about a system with memory errors. In that case the expr binary was cached and the writer was able to get it to reload from disk by dropping the caches on his system.

As always, be careful, this could have consequences for performance of the machine while the caches get primed again.

Answer (score 0):

Might be solution is like above but in my case I had **/etc/nail.rc** in use.
I observed one extra space in below line in /etc/nail.rc

```
set smtp= smtp.mailserver.com
```

I just removed the space (after = )and it worked. I think sendmail was looking for authentication and  was not getting it. Sendmail doesn't understand spaces.